# Google App engine MemCache - ArrayList persistence

Tags: google-app-engine, arraylist, memcached

I want to store an ArrayList to GAE memcache. I know that there is no guarantee that the data remains, so if i store an arraylist this means that i lose ALL of the items in the list right?

I want to know it because i want the all items to be there or no items at all. No partial item removals are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you store the array list in a single memcache value, if the value is evicted, then the entire array list is evicted.